# PiCamera and Flask - Start and Stop Preview/Record

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program, which will start and stop for first preview on different POST request. My Code is look like this:

```
from flask import Flask
import time
import picamera
import logging
import sys
import os
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    from cStringIO import StringIO as bio
else:
    from io import BytesIO as bio

app = Flask(__name__)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s '
                    + '[%(filename)s:%(lineno)s:%(funcName)s()] %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

@app.route("/start", methods=['POST'])
def start_preview():
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (1920, 1080)
        camera.start_preview()
        time.sleep(300)

@app.route("/stop", methods=['POST'])
def stop_preview():
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.stop_preview()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='192.168.0.198', port='8080')
```

When I'm trying to start preview, it's works, but the /stop request do nothing. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I wrote a little script for RPi with some functions and will bring this project till the end. https://github.com/IljaGrebel/PiCamera-Controll

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are creating a new instance of PiCamera in your stop_preview function, so the stop_preview isn't acting on the same instance as the start_preview.

Try defining a variable to hold a reference to the PiCamera at the application level. Then use the same variable in both functions.

Comment: I solved it already. When my code is ready, I will post it here.